# abrir y renderizar archivo pdf en el navegador

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy intentando abrir un archivo PDF que he almacenado en una carpeta de mi app pero al abrir la pestaña donde se supone que se tiene que renderizar el archivo PDF me sale el siguiente error: "Este documento PDF podria no mostrarse correctamente".

aca el controlador que se ejecuta al tratar de visualizar el pdf:

```
exports.verReglamento = function(req, res) {
    models.regla.findOne({
        where: { id: req.params.id }
    }).then(Reglamento => {
        var filePath = "../../public/uploads/index/conocenos/reglamentos/constancia.pdf";

        fs.readFile(filePath , function (err,data){
            res.contentType("application/pdf");
            res.send(data);
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.json(err);
    })
}
```

Comment: El problema no está en tu aplicación sino en el navegador. ¿Has probado diferentes navegadores? ¿Tienes Adobe Reader plugin instalado para el navegador?

Comment: instale el plugin, abre una interfaz para pdf pero al tratar de cargar el archivo retorna una alerta diciendo lo siguiente: "se ha producido un error al cargar el documento PDF"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo,encontré una solución.

mi enlace para ejecutar esta acción quedo asi:

```html
<a href="/admin/conocenos/verReglamento/<%- Reglas[i].id %>" target="_blank">
```

Mi ruta es la Siguiente

```js
app.get('/admin/conocenos/verReglamento/:id', isLoggedIn, adminController.verReglamento);
```

y mi controlador hace lo siguiente:

```js
exports.verReglamento = function(req, res) {
 models.regla.findOne({
  where: { id: req.params.id }
 }).then(Reglamento => {
   var ruta = path.join(__dirname , '../../public/uploads/index/conocenos/reglamentos/');

     res.sendFile(ruta+Reglamento.pdf);
 }).catch(err => {
  res.json(err);
 })
}
```